# consider a string which has question marks, numbers , letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

consider a string which has question marks, numbers , letters. 
check for three question marks between two numbers where in when adding those two numbers it should be 10.In that case return it as string true or else string false.example: "bdhfr6???4hfyrt5???eee5".Above example return string true because between 6 and 4 there are 3 question marks and between 5 and 5 exactly 3 question marks
or else false

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please show us your code, we will help you, but not do your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave the refactoring of regex on you, but this is something you can do using [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
function checkStr(str) {
 let match = str.match(/(\d)\?{3}(\d)/);
 return match && +match[1] + +match[2] === 10;
}

let out = checkStr('bdhfr6???3hfyrt5???eee5');
console.log(out)

out = checkStr('bdhfr6???4hfyrt5???eee5');
console.log(out)
```